# ASP.NET MVC - keep links to the root folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to link inside the same folder, I have the following structure

```
/Home/Index
/Home/About
/Home/Contact
```

When I start the webpage, I link to the `Index`, so I get the webpage on the screen: `www.example.com`.

Now I would like to link to another page so I get: `www.example.com/Contact.html` (or even better I would like to get `www.example.com/Contact`) however I get `www.example.com/Home/Contact`.

I use this as an action link:

```
<li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected">@Html.ActionLink("Contact us", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

This is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What could I change to get the desired result?

Comment: thanks Marc_s for the spelling and layout correction, really helped me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate you Contact action with a RouteAttribute and pass it the desired route as parameter (i.e. "Contact")

**Edit**

Here's an example HomeController using the RouteAttribute:

```
public class HomeController
     : Controller
{

      public IActionResult Home()
      {
          return this.View();
      }

      [Route("Contact")]
      public IActionResult Contact()
      {
          return this.View();
      }

}
```

Note that you can use the RouteAttribute on Controllers, too. For instance, if I added a **Route("Test")** attribute on the HomeController, all of my controllers actions would look like: "/Test/[ActionRoute]".

In your views, you can use the following syntax, instead of using the old @Html.ActionLink tag helper:

```
<li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected">
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

In my opinion, those attribute tag helpers are way cleaner and html friendly ;)

Comment: thanks, how does the final result look like in this case? www.example.com/Contact or www.example.com/Home/Contact ?

Comment: In this case, it will look like www.example.com/Contact ;)
Try it out! If it works for you, please mark my post as the asnwer ;)

Answer (score -1):

i was able to fix it with some good reading and searching and this is what i came up with:

i added this to the routeConfig for each link to a html page:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 routes.MapRoute("About", "About", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
 routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
```

and instead of using an action link i use a route link:

```
 <li class="pure-menu-item">@Html.RouteLink("About us", "About")</li>
```

this gives the desired result: www.example.com/About

Comment: It doesn't seem to me as a good solution, way too many routes being configured, and this doesn't look like maintainable in the long run, whereas using the RouteAttribute is, which is exactly what it is intended for. You can configure all your actions independently without having to declare a new patterns.

Comment: ok, can you show an example how to use the RouteAtribute in that case and how the end result would look like?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to provide you with all the requested info ;)