# How to add route to mvc for a view without changing in other view URLs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5 in visual studio 2017.
I add a route to my MVC project but I want to some views use test route and use Default route. what can I do? 
I make a route in mvc `RouteConfig.cs` like this :

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "test",
                url: "test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

but the url for any view is something like that :
[image]

how can I force `Contact` view to use `Default` routing?

Comment: Does your contact view also load for `/Home/Contact`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'default' route pattern before the 'test' one in your configuration? 
Otherwise, make use of the **RouteAttribute**, as I explained it in this post: [ASP.NET MVC - keep links to the root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235122/asp-net-mvc-keep-links-to-the-root-folder/61239080#61239080)

Comment: Is it possible you could include some of the important parts of the post you linked in with your answer, in case they are useful for others? Links can go bad over time and some of the information might be vital to the OP or future visitors solving the problem.

Comment: Also, you could further improve your answer by offering some example code on how the OP could use your suggestion, which will make it a lot more valuable for the OP and future visitors to use.